# Firebase Auth issue when registering users, automatic sign in when register?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The problem happens when I register a new user with the functions provided by FB Auth.

When I register a new user it triggers the observer [onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged), which I thought it would only be triggered when a user signs in.

```
//user register
btnReg.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('creating account');
    auth.
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(regmail.value,regpass.value)
            .then(userCredential => {
                regform.reset();
                console.log('successfully registered');
            })
});

//user login
btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('trying to sign in');
    auth.
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(logmail.value,logpassw.value)
    .then(userCredential => {
        console.log('logged in');
        signout.style.display = 'block';
        logform.reset();
    })
});


//check user state
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        console.log('auth: logged in');
        signout.style.display = 'block';
        wheader.appendChild(signout)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Authentication works that way. If you don't want that behavior you can sign out user immediately after login.

```
const authListener = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        console.log('auth: logged in');
        signout.style.display = 'block';
        wheader.appendChild(signout)
    }
});

//When user clicks register, 
authListener()

auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(logmail.value,logpassw.value).then(userCredential => {
  auth.signOut().then(() => {
    // redirect somewhere
  })
})
```

You may not want your authStateChanged listener to trigger during that period so when user clicks the register button, disable to auth listener as shown above.

Other way would be creating user accounts using [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) in a Cloud functions or your server. You can read more about [creating new user]https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user() in the documentation. But if the immediate signout works for you then there's no need for Cloud functions.

Comment: So I should register the user and then call the sign-out as a part of my register fuction?

Comment: @MatiasLapolla yes. Then just redirect user to login page maybe so they can login with their new account.

Comment: Thank you! I can't up-vote yet but I will as soon as I can. Just tried it and worked as I expected :)

Comment: @MatiasLapolla glad to hear that. You can click on the tick icon to accept the answer so others will know the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround will be to use Shared Preferences to handle if everything in registration has been completed first then the stream builder listens to redirect the users to a screen to either back to the